# Function firing before images has finished loading

Tags: javascript, image, preloader

I'm trying to get a pre loader screen to work but am hitting a roadblock.

My goal: To have the loading animation/divs dissapear when the image has finished loading.

I've tried to accomplish this with a simple .ready function and still the function that removes the loading animation fires white the image is still loading and the viewer will see the image load in real time.

```
$("#defaultImage").ready(function(){
  TweenMax.to(["#backgroundLoad","#loadBoxes"],1,{alpha:0,delay:0.75});
  console.log('Page has loaded'); 
});
```

Is this incorrect? I thought that this will wait for the entire page(images included) to load and then fire the function inside it.

I've tried the below too and it doesn't seem to fire the console.log at all

```
document.getElementById("defaultImage").onload = function (){
  console.log('Page has loaded'); 
};
```

Pen in question below. You can see the issue if you view it in debug view and do a hard refresh.
http://codepen.io/mhcreative/pen/GoxLPo?editors=0011

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks, All.

Comment: What you are trying to do is you are calling your callbacks on load of element i.e when element is rendered on browser and not when images are loaded. One solution is instead of writing your own code you can use imagesLoaded library

Comment: looks like its working to me. note that your tween function has a 0.75 second delay so the user always has to wait that long between the loader disappearing and the image showing on the page

Comment: Thanks @ Zeeshan Hyder imagesLoaded library worked perfectly. Desandro is 3 for 3 in the JS library quality. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here try this if you still want it natively.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var img = new Image();   // Create new img element
    img.addEventListener("load", function() {
     TweenMax.to(["#backgroundLoad","#loadBoxes"],1,{alpha:0,delay:0.75});
    }, false);
    img.src = 'src/to/img'; // Set source path
    $("#defaultImage").append(img); //append loaded image inside div
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you and I'm now noticing that you suggested the the imagesloaded library too. You're 2 for 2. Keep up the good work. Much appreciated.

Comment: So glad it helped. :)